# Window borders corrupted

Tags: unity

My UI is corrupted (after going into sleep mode).
[corrupted borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUOR6.png)

What do I do to reset this without rebooting?
I tried:
- change screen resolution
- change ubuntu theme

That did not fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Nvidia drivers?

Comment: yes, nvidia drivers

Comment: Experiencing this problem as well. Also experiencing [bug #1662860](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1662860) but don't know if that is related. My temporary fix is to restart Unity with alt+F2 and typing "unity". This always causes Firefox to close but my other windows stay open.